# 被害 vs 害; 被害者 vs 害者

Tags: nuances

I was reading NHK NEWS WEB EASY and came across the word "被害". When I encounter a new word, I try to break it down and understand each part.

And then it looked to me like 被害 and 害 have the same meaning, at first.
Wiktionary says that 被 is a prefix that marks the passive recipient of an action.

So, 被害 would be something like "passive injury"? And 害 would be just "injury"? Does "passive" just mean "the recipient didn't do anything to have the event happen to them"?

Do people just use the word 害 alone when they don't want to specify if it's passive or not?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

害 and 被害 are usually not interchangeable. 害 just means "harm", whereas 被害 specifically refers to accidental damage **someone took** due to a crime, traffic accident, natural disaster or such. If you want to understand 被害 literally, it would be something like "received harm" or "taken damage". (Note that "passive" is one of the [many meanings of 被](https://jisho.org/search/%E8%A2%AB%20%23kanji).) For example you can say この番組には害がある ("This TV program is harmful"), but not この番組には被害がある.

Comment: そういえば警察の隠語で「ガイシャ」と言っても被害者のことですね（笑）